# Javascript On Youtube Video Started

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, click

I have an yotube video embedded in my page. I'm trying to make an watch count when iframed youtube video has started. For example when the client clicks to play button on the youtube video, it will send a data to my webserver and play the video. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it directly due to security reasons. A work around can be to wrap the video with an image or a div and once you click on the image trigger the youtube video iframe. This click on the image or div can be listened to by using an event handler on it. Check out the following link if it helps

[How can I track a click event of an embedded video (youtube, vimeo, etc.)? (to track play count)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260605/how-can-i-track-a-click-event-of-an-embedded-video-youtube-vimeo-etc-to-t)